# Отправка на почту через gmail openserver

Tags: php, email

Хочу отправить на почту сообщение, но не получается и никаких ошибок не показывает, спам проверял. В логах написано, что вроде бы всё отправляется:

```
To: kamahinmihail@gmail.com
Subject: Тема
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:index.php
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
From: тест <kamahinmihail@gmail.com>

<html>
        <head>
            <title>Письмо</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Это письмо пришло вам с Мой сайт</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Страница, с которой отправляю сообщение:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

    $subject = 'Тема';
    $to = 'kamahinmihail@gmail.com';
    $from = 'kamahinmihail@gmail.com';
    $message = ' 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Письмо</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Это письмо пришло вам с Мой сайт</p>
        </body>
    </html>';
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: тест <$from>\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

В openserver в поле пароль ввёл свой пароль от почты gmail.com

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также при первой отправке сообщения на почту пришло сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел отправлять сообщение по почту без ввода своего пароля, google мне на это вроде намекает

Answer (score 0):

Если отправлять не с реального сайта сообщение, то в своей почте гугла надо указать, чтобы разрешить получать доступ ненадёжным приложениям к своему аккаунту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что делать, если Gmail почта больше не дает выставить данный переключатель в разделе безопасности? Кто решил проблему ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 делать почту от хостинга